# Specify a function with unknown coefficients as well as data and find coefficients in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, minimize, mse

I have a function: f(theta) = a+b*cos(theta - c) as well as sampled data. I'd like to find the coefficients a, b, and c that minimize mean square error. Any idea if there's an efficient way to do this in python?

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#definition of the function 
def myfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * np.cos(x - c)

#sample data
x_data = [0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300]
y_data = [25, 40, 70, 30, 10, 15]

#the actual curve fitting procedure, a, b, c are stored in popt
popt, _pcov = curve_fit(myfunc, x_data, y_data)
print(popt)
print(np.degrees(popt[2]))

#the rest is just a graphic representation of the data points and the fitted curve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#x_fit = np.linspace(-1, 6, 1000)
y_fit = myfunc(x_data, *popt)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, "ro")
plt.plot(x_data, y_fit, "b")
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$ (degrees)');
plt.ylabel(r'$f(\theta)$');

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is a picture showing how the curve doesn't really fit the points. It seems like the amplitude should be higher. The local mins and maxes appear to be in the right places.

[image]

Comment: It seems you are looking for [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). It should not be difficult to implement your desired function, just look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: @Mr.T just edited the question - curve fit doesn't seem to have the right amplitude. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) makes it really easy to fit data points to your custom function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#definition of the function 
def myfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * np.cos(x - c)

#sample data
x_data = np.arange(5)
y_data = 2.34 + 1.23 * np.cos(x_data + .23)

#the actual curve fitting procedure, a, b, c are stored in popt
popt, _pcov = curve_fit(myfunc, x_data, y_data)
print(popt)

#the rest is just a graphic representation of the data points and the fitted curve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x_fit = np.linspace(-1, 6, 1000)
y_fit = myfunc(x_fit, *popt)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, "ro", label = "data points")
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, "b", label = "fitted curve\na = {}\nb = {}\nc = {}".format(*popt))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[ 2.34  1.23 -0.23]
```

**Edit:**

Your question update introduces several problems. First, your x-values are in degree, while [`np.cos`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html) expects values in radians. Therefore, we better convert the values with [`np.deg2rad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.deg2rad.html#numpy.deg2rad). The reverse function would be [`np.rad2deg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rad2deg.html#numpy.rad2deg).
Second, it is a good idea to fit for different frequencies as well, let's introduce an additional parameter for that.
Third, fits are usually quite sensitive to initial guesses. You can provide a parameter `p0` in `scipy` for that.
Fourth, you changed the resolution of the fitted curve to the low resolution of your data points, hence it looks so undersampled. If we address all these problems:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#sample data
x_data = [0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300]
y_data = [25, 40, 70, 30, 10, 15]

#definition of the function with additional frequency value d
def myfunc(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b * np.cos(d * np.deg2rad(x) - c)
#initial guess of parameters a, b, c, d
p_initial = [np.average(y_data), np.average(y_data), 0, 1]

#the actual curve fitting procedure, a, b, c, d are stored in popt
popt, _pcov = curve_fit(myfunc, x_data, y_data, p0 = p_initial)
print(popt)
#we have to convert the phase shift back into degrees
print(np.rad2deg(popt[2]))

#graphic representation of the data points and the fitted curve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#define x_values for a smooth curve representation
x_fit = np.linspace(np.min(x_data), np.max(x_data), 1000)
y_fit = myfunc(x_fit, *popt)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, "ro", label = "data")
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, "b", label = "fit")
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$ (degrees)');
plt.ylabel(r'$f(\theta)$');

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

we get this output:

```
[34.31293761 26.92479369  2.20852009  1.18144319]
126.53888003953764
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, however, my curve doesn't appear to actually fit closely to the points. I edited my post to reflect this.